# Error in accessing Zuul config management

Tags: spring-boot

I installed Zuul in my local machine following the steps in https://github.com/Confluex/Zuul/wiki/Installation. 
When I try to access the Zuul http://localhost:8080/zuul/login it asks for URL to login. And it is not mentioned anywhere what is the default URL.

Any ideas??